# Permission Sets on Quotes Template

Tags: community, security, permissions, configuration

I would like to create a permission set to give an access to all quote templates.

I do not want some users within the same profile to see or have access to the quotes template.

How to user can only access quote in App setup menu > Customize > Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

please go through following information:
 
**Customizing Quote PDFs with Quote Templates**
Available in: Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

**User Permissions Needed**

To create quote templates:        "Customize Application"

To view quote templates:          "View Setup and Configuration"

Use quote templates to design, preview, and activate custom templates for the quotes you send to your customers.

**Navigating the Quote Templates Editor**
The template editor has two parts: a palette at the top and a template layout below.
The palette contains the elements you can add to the layout, including list and section, and fields that you can add to sections.

- Click  beneath the palette to expand or collapse it.
- In the left column, select an object to display its fields on the
  palette.
- Use Quick Find to easily locate items on the palette.

**Working with the Quote Templates Editor**

- To add an element to the template, drag it from the palette to the
  layout. Use a section to add and arrange fields from the quote
  object. Use a list to create a table with fields from another object,
  such as quote line item. The Text/Image Field lets you enter text or
  upload an image, such as your company logo.
- Press CTRL+click to select multiple fields and SHIFT+click to select
  a range.
- To remove an element from the layout, drag it back to the palette, or
  hover over its title bar and click .
- When you drag a section, select Hide Title if you don't want the
  section's title to appear on the template or the PDF.
- For any section, (including a header or footer), you can change the
  number of columns, adjust field alignment, and hide or show field
  labels. Click  and make the changes you want.
- To step backward or forward, click Undo and Redo.
- To change the properties of any component on the layout, double-click
  its title bar or click .
- To rename the template, click Quote Template Properties.
- To preview your template, click Save and Preview.
- To save your changes and continue editing the template, click Quick
  Save.
- To save your changes when you're finished editing the template,
  click Save.
- Don't navigate away from the template before clicking Save or you'll
  lose your changes.

You can also go through following url: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=quotes_template_create.htm&language=en_US

Hope this helps you!

Thanks